# PHP send form does not work on a specific web host

Tags: php, email, web-hosting

I have a problem with my web host, I been trying to call the support but no answer yet, so I trying here

I have this simple PHP code that sends an mail to my gmail, the code works fine on my other hosting site, but on www.one.com the php just shows "Your email was sent." but there is no email send. I have set the permisions to 777 on the file, but no luck.

Is there anything i can do to fix this or is it an problem for my web host?

This is my code

```
<?php 
    $name = "MyName";
    $email = "MyName@gmail.com";
    $message = "This is a test";

    $to = 'Myothermail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
    $headers = 'From: www.mysite.se' . "\r\n";

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert_box'>Your email was sent.</div>"; // success message

    }
        else
    {
        echo " <div class='alert alert-error alert_box'>Your email address is invalid. Please enter a valid address.</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: "but no answer yet" sounds like you need a new host

Comment: Web hotel? Do you mean web *host*?

Comment: You're not checking the result of `mail()`, so it will say that the email is sent regardless of whether it actually was.

Comment: This `$headers = 'From: www.mysite.se' . "\r\n";` is invalid. It should be an email address and not a Web site address/URL. In some cases, mail will be rejected or sent to Spam; so, check your Spam box.

Comment: Check for exceptions with try{ mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); } catch(Exception $e) { var_dump($e); }

Comment: You might want to try sending the from in the mail call itself
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,'-fwebmaster@example.com');  Maybe enable error reporting also to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your script shows that your email was sent because you're not actually checking anything. [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) returns true if successful and false otherwise so:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { //This method sends the mail.
      echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert_box'>Your email was sent.</div>"; // success message
   } else 
   {
      echo "<div class='alert alert-error alert_box'>Mail send problem.</div>";
   }
}
    else
{
    echo " <div class='alert alert-error alert_box'>Your email address is invalid. Please enter a valid address.</div>";
}
```

Can you check the logs, or enable error reporting?

Comment: Thank you, Now i get mail send problem on the web hoster that is messing with me, in the other one its working like a charm...